# Can anybody help me how to construct a table like this in latex?

Tags: diagrams

[image]

I reproduced the table in latex with the code above but I do not know how convert the line into an arrow

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  

\begin{document}  

$\begin{pgfpicture}{0.0cm}{0.0cm}{8.0cm}{8.0cm}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.5pt}
    % Row 1  
    \pgfnoderect{A1}[stroke]{\pgfxy(1,4)}{\pgfxy(2,2)}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(0.5,4.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(1.5,4.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$6$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(0.5,3.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$$}}    
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(1.5,3.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$$}}    
    \pgfnoderect{A2}[stroke]{\pgfxy(3,4)}{\pgfxy(2,2)}    
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(2.5,4.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$$}}    
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(3.5,4.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$10$}}    
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(2.5,3.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(3.5,3.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$$}}  
    \pgfnoderect{B1}[stroke]{\pgfxy(1.5,4.5)}{\pgfxy(1,1)}  
    \pgfnoderect{B2}[stroke]{\pgfxy(3.5,4.5)}{\pgfxy(1,1)}  
    % Row 2  
    \pgfnoderect{A3}[stroke]{\pgfxy(1,6)}{\pgfxy(2,2)}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(0.5,6.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(1.5,6.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$5$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(0.5,5.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(1.5,5.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$$}}  
    \pgfnoderect{A4}[stroke]{\pgfxy(3,6)}{\pgfxy(2,2)}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(2.5,6.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(3.5,6.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$9$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(2.5,5.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(3.5,5.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$$}}  
    \pgfnoderect{B3}[stroke]{\pgfxy(1.5,6.5)}{\pgfxy(1,1)}  
    \pgfnoderect{B4}[stroke]{\pgfxy(3.5,6.5)}{\pgfxy(1,1)}  
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(4.5,3.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$32$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(4.5,5.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$28$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(3.0,7.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$v_{2}=2$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(1.0,7.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$v_{1}=4$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(-1.0,3.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$u_{2}=-2$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(-1.0,5.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$u_{1}=-3$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(0.5,2.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$48$}}  
    \pgfputat{\pgfxy(2.5,2.5)}{\pgfbox[center,center]{$29$}}  
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
    \pgfsetendarrow{\pgfarrowsingle}  
    \pgfxycurve(4.75,4.25)(4.75,4.25)(3.75,3.5)(3.75,3.5)  
\end{pgfpicture}$  

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Can you explain, what means added code in your question?

Comment: @Zarko See the revision history message. EMGA: I added your edit message to the post. Was the code generated by `jpgfdraw` or something?

Comment: @TorbjørnT., there seems to be duplication of this question, one of them I edit before. I haven't any idea how this code is generated. Also its purpose is not clear to me.

Comment: @Zarko The purpose of the code? It generates a diagram much like the one in the image, just try and you'll see.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. , this I see, but which line hat to be converted?  Slanted one? I assume this in addendum to my answer ...

Answer (score 8):

As image is simple:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0mm,
box/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum size=#1, outer sep = 0pt}
                    ]
\node (n11) [box=20mm,label=above:{$v_1=4$},label=left:{$u_1=-3$}] {};
\node (n12) [box=20mm,label=above:{$v_2=2$},label=right:28,right=of n11] {};
\node (n21) [box=20mm,label=left:{$u_2=-2$},label=below:48,below=of n11] {};
\node (n22) [box=20mm,label=right:32,label=below:29,right=of n21] {};
%
\node (n11a) [box=10mm,below left=of n11.north east] {5};
\node (n12a) [box=10mm,below left=of n12.north east] {9};
\node (n21a) [box=10mm,below left=of n21.north east] {6};
\node (n2a2) [box=10mm,below left=of n22.north east] {10};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Let assume, that slanted line at number 32 had to be arrows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0mm,
box/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum size=#1, outer sep = 0pt}
                    ]
\node (n11) [box=20mm,
             label=195:{$u_1=-3$},% on the left side
             label=above:{$v_1=4$}] {};
\node (n12) [box=20mm,
             label=above:{$v_2=2$},
             label=-15:28,% on the right side
             right=of n11] {};
\node (n21) [box=20mm,
             label=195:{$u_2=-2$},% on the left side
             label=below:48,
             below=of n11] {};
\node (n22) [box=20mm,
            label=-15:32,% on the right side
            label=below:29,
            right=of n21] {};
    %
\node (n11a) [box=10mm,below left=of n11.north east] {5};
\node (n12a) [box=10mm,below left=of n12.north east] {9};
\node (n21a) [box=10mm,below left=of n21.north east] {6};
\node (n2a2) [box=10mm,below left=of n22.north east] {10};
% added arrows
\draw[->] ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=5mm] n22.south east) -- + (45:9mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

in above code also labels are moved to position as it shown in image in question. Result is:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As an array in a math environment you can use `\multicolumn` to span several columns. There is a package `multirow` that can be used similarly to center over several rows as in Zarko's answer, but this is not how it is specified in the question figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{array}{r|p{1.3em}|p{1.3em}|p{1.3em}|p{1.3em}|l}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{v_1=4} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{v_2=2}\\\cline{2-5}
    & & 5 & & 9 & \\\cline{3-3}\cline{5-5}
    u_1=-3 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & 28 \\\cline{2-5}
    & & 6 & & 10 & \\\cline{3-3}\cline{5-5}
    u_2=-2 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & 32 \\\cline{2-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{48} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{29}
  \end{array}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image]